# PL/SQL: master detail loop using cursors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I currently have a master detail using a single cursor

```
DECLARE 
   CURSOR emps_cur (department_id_in IN INTEGER) 
   IS 
    select ENAME,DNAME,d.DEPTNO
    from scott.EMP e, scott.DEPT d 
    where d.DEPTNO = e.DEPTNO;
BEGIN 
   FOR rec IN emps_cur (1700) 
   LOOP 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rec.DEPTNO||' '||rec.DNAME); 
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rec.ENAME); 
   END LOOP; 
END;
/
```

Which results in:

```
Statement processed.
10 ACCOUNTING
CLARK
10 ACCOUNTING
MILLER
10 ACCOUNTING
KING
20 RESEARCH
FORD
20 RESEARCH
SCOTT
20 RESEARCH
JONES
20 RESEARCH
SMITH
20 RESEARCH
ADAMS
30 SALES
WARD
30 SALES
MARTIN
30 SALES
TURNER
30 SALES
JAMES
30 SALES
ALLEN
30 SALES
BLAKE
```

I've been trying to figure out how to loop it so the results look like this:

```
10 ACCOUNTING
  CLARK
  MILLER
  KING
20 RESEARCH
  FORD
  SCOTT
  JONES
  SMITH
  ADAMS
30 SALES
  WARD
  MARTIN
  TURNER
  JAMES
  ALLEN
  BLAKE
```

Essentially, print deptno and dname and the assigned employees right below (with no duplicates). Sorry if this seems elementary. Just started trying to learn PL/SQL and I can't find an answer from search engines.

Comment: I'm not familiar with an `dept` table, that store the values you seem to be seeing in your output. It's not the usual default `dept`.

Comment: On a side note: You should not use comma-separated joins anymore. They have been made redundant in 1992. Use explicit joins instead `from scott.emp e join scott.dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Noted, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE
```

> ```
>    vCurrentDeptName dept.DNAME%type := 'impossible name';
> ```

```
   CURSOR emps_cur (department_id_in IN INTEGER) 
   IS 
    select ENAME,DNAME,JOB 
    from scott.EMP e, scott.DEPT d 
    where d.DEPTNO = e.DEPTNO;
BEGIN 
   FOR rec IN emps_cur (1700) 
   LOOP
```

> ```
>     if vCurrentDeptName != rec.DNAME then
>        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rec.DNAME); 
>        vCurrentDeptName := rec.DNAME;
>     end if;
> ```

```
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (rec.ENAME); 
   END LOOP; 
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable v_dname valorised at the end of the loop with ref.dname. At the beginning of the loop, compare rec.dname with v_dname.  If the value is the same, you are in the same department, and you don't dbms it.